# Erro de JavaScript no admin do Wordpress após atualização para versão 3.8

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Recentemente atualizei uma instalação do WordPress 3.0 para o 3.8 e as funcionalidades de *drag and drop* pararam de funcionar.

Percebi dois erros de JavaScript na página no arquivo `load-scripts.php` indicando uma *token ILLEGAL*. O erro que peguei do console do chrome é esse:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,jquery-ui-core…pabl‌​e,admin-widgets,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,thickbox&ver=3.8:2

Já desabilitei todos os plugins e outros passos indicados em um post no fórum do [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/drag-and-drop-function-lost), mas mesmo assim não resolveu o problema.

Comment: Coloque o erro aqui, para podermos te ajudar melhor. Outra coisa, se possível verifique através do Firebug do Firefox, ele é melhor para debugar erros de javascript.

Comment: De que forma é que o teu erro está relacionado com o Apache para teres essa tag na pergunta?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no código fonte do arquivo via aba network do firebug, talvez haja um erro de php.

Comment: Chegou a tentar o que eu falei? se nao deu certo procuro outra alternativa...

Comment: Olá kenny, desculpe a demora... realmente ainda não fucionou...

Comment: @Zuul realmente... coloquei porque era php... corrigido...

Comment: Eita...vou procurar uma solução e posto aqui...

Comment: Em vez de dizer "... e outros passos indicados em um post no fórum do WordPress", seria melhor listar quais foram esses outros passos. Mesmo existindo um link, ele pode se quebrar no futuro, ou podem surgir novos posts no fórum linkado depois de você ter feito a pergunta, e um leitor futuro pode concluir que você fez algum passo que não tenha sido feito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procurando mais um pouco encontrei no StackOverflow em inglês uma [alternativa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654426/wordpress-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal) que funcionou. No final foi necessário alterar o php.ini e desabilitar as seguintes variáveis de configuração:

```
magic_quotes_gpc
magic_quotes_runtime
magic_quotes_sybase
```

Com isso, deu certo.

Comment: Se esta resposta foi o que resolveu o problema, sugiro que marque a mesma como "aceita", clicando no "tique" abaixo do placar da resposta. Isso vai levá-la ao topo da lista de respostas.

Answer (score 3):

Jamais mexa nos arquivos do *core* do WordPress, nem que seja o jQuery.

Se está desconfiado que algo do pacote quebrou, faça o download novamente e substitua os arquivos.

Faça um backup do arquivo `wp-config.php` e da pasta `wp-content`.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer o download do JQUERY original, no mínimo a versão 1.6.1, copie o conteúdo e substitua o do arquivo `wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js`.

Comment: Desculpa, mas a sugestão é terrível... Não entendo o voto positivo...

Comment: O que há de terrível nisto? respeito opiniões, desde que sejam baseadas em argumentos. Quando se quer criticar algo você mostra o que há de errado.

Comment: É fato, se vc fez a sugestão é porque não sabe que [*cada vez que modificamos os arquivos fontes do WordPress um gatinho morre*](http://websynthesis.com/dont-hack-wordpress-core/). Em geral, o erro é fazer um `dequeue` do jQuery embutido e carregar de um CDN, mas é a primeira vez que vejo a sugestão de substituir diretamente no código fonte.

Answer (score -1):

Para resolver esse problema, pegue a versão mais recente do Wordpress, no tema mais recente, e copie o arquivo 'functions.php' e a pasta 'inc' para o seu tema atual.